# How to use where in when value is array in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array like this

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "05046"
  1 => "05005"
  2 => "05030"
]
```

and i want to show the location based on their id in array above (the id is 05046,05005,05030. how to applied it in my controller below?

actually I want to query something like this using where in. when the id i put manual, it works.

```
$location= Location::whereIn('id',['05046','05005','05030'])->get();
```

But, since the id that i get is in array, how to apply it in controller?

```
$location= Location::whereIn('id',[$val])->get();
```

i try this with $val but in select option in the blade, the location only show the latest id (array no 2)
$val when dd($val) will show

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "05046"
  1 => "05005"
  2 => "05030"
]
```

the blade

```
<select class="select" name="loc" id="loc" required="">
     @foreach ($location as $loc)
            <option value="{{$loc->id}}">{{$loc->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: you get only 1 record (array 2) with `Location::whereIn('id',[05046,05005,05030])->get();` ?

Comment: Location::whereIn('id',[05046,05005,05030])->get();
with this can show all, but when use $val, it only show 1 id

Comment: Let me know, you got the same result with these 2 query? `Location::whereIn('id',[05046,05005,05030])->get();` and `Location::whereIn('id',["05046","05005","05030"])->get();`

Comment: ah sorry, in my example, forgot to add quote (') and i use this my code actually,  Location::whereIn('id',["05046","05005","05030"])  with quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your mistake. If you already have the $val array:

```
$val = [
  0 => "05046"
  1 => "05005"
  2 => "05030"
];
```

dont add `[]` brackets when using it inside `whereIn` because then you are declaring that its an array inside an array. `whereIn` requires the second parameter to be a regular array. Simply do this:

```
$location= Location::whereIn('id', $val)->get();
```